# SwiftUI Buttons (and everything else) with no style become unresponsive when other Button with custom style are present on screen on MacOS Catalyst

Tags: ios, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I'm having this issue with SwiftUI on Mac Catalyst wherein a simple view like the following :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var count : Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Button("tap me"){
                count += 1
            }
            Button("test \(count)"){
                count += 1
            }.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
            Button("test \(count)"){
                count += 1
            }.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
            Button("test \(count)"){
                count += 1
            }.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
    }
}
```

The button with no style (but also everything else from pickers to sliders) becomes unresponsive after a number of renders.
This happens only when two or more Buttons with custom style are visible on the screen.
Having different styles doesn't solve the issue.
Have you encountered this issue before? Is it a bug with SwiftUI on mac?

Comment: I've tried your code and all is working well for me on mac 11.3-beta, using xcode 12.5-beta, targets ios 14.x, mac catalyst 11.3.

Comment: that's interesting. To replicate the issue you should have pressed repeatedly on all three buttons with custom style at least once. Have you done that? Thanks for trying @workingdog

Comment: yes done that, clicked the buttons many many times. Tried different sequences as well, and all is still working well.

Comment: FWIW, I also checked (since I'm having similar non-responsiveness-after-a-while issues with TextField), but it all works for me and does not become unresponsive. XCode 12.4.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this problem is reproducible when deploying using "Optimize Interface for Mac". If you use "Scale Interface to Match iPad", it works without a problem. Specifying a contentShape fixes the problem for some reason. FWIW, just specifying the contentShape for the non-custom (i.e., native when using "Optimize Interface for Mac") works in a VStack, but not in an HStack.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("tap me") { count += 1 }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            Button("test \(count)") { count += 1 }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
            Button("test \(count)") { count += 1 }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
            Button("test \(count)") { count += 1 }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
        }
    }
    
}

struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yes! I missed to mention that I'm building an app for Mac and iOS so that 'optimize for Mac ' option is enabled for me.

Comment: It seems that specifying the contentShape fixes the problem, altho I don't really understand what's going on behind the scenes with SwiftUI in "Optimize Interface for Mac" that makes this so. It caused me problems when using Button along with TextField. Providing code above.

Comment: In hopes it might one day be fixed, I filed FB9101621